# iOS How do you get all configured mail accounts

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, iphone, xamarin

Is it possible to get all configured email accounts of the device? And how can I access them, which class?

Examples can be in Objective C or C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, Apple has no API that allows access to the mail accounts.

Comment: How can i add events into another email accounts now than ?

Comment: You can't and you where never able. Apple only allows sending of e-mail via the [`MFMailComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/). There is not access to mail account directly.